# How to access defined in the application.properties file in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

I want to access values provided in application.properties, e.g.:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate: ERROR
logging.file=${HOME}/application.log

userBucket.path=${HOME}/bucket
```

I want to access userBucket.path in my main program in a Spring Boot application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the @Value annotation and access the property in whichever Spring bean you're using

```
@Value("${userBucket.path}")
private String userBucketPath;
```